# Increment column value on SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build an API and one of the endpoints will return a random row from my database. In the database I have a table in which I want a "views" column to be updated every time I run a SELECT query on a row.

My table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The row is selected by ordering the table with rand() and then limiting the result by 1, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

Is something like this below possible?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
UPDATE table SET views = +1 WHERE (selected row?);
```

I'm new to SQL queries, so I don't know if this is the best way or even possible at all. Should I run a new query after this one has completed that updates the value instead?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do here.  Your current query would return one random row, but what else do you need beyond this?

Comment: I want to increment the value of the "views" column in this returned row and was wondering if it is possible to do so in the same query as the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, every table has a Primary Key, i.e. a unique ID of every single row. Since you have a result of your `SELECT` query and it's only 1 row, you always can make a consequent update query like `UPDATE table SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = <returned_record_id>`. Here we assume that the column `id` is a Primary Key column. This pair of queries need to be issued by the application code. If you want to achieve `SELECT + UPDATE` functionality as a single SQL statement, consider using stored procedures.

While the aforementioned approach is technically possible, it might have a few performance problems. First of, `ORDER BY rand()` often has a poor performance. Also, having an update on each select could have bad performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

No what you want is not possible .as, select and update commands can not be used togethor in a single transaction.
You can do it seperately

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a procedure for this in your database like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_name`()

BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 ;

    UPDATE table SET views = +1 WHERE (selected row?) ;

END
```

and then call it

```
call procedure_name();
```

You can check only as there are many ways to write a procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you want to do is not possible, at least not without a lot of work.  SQL in general -- and MySQL in particular -- offer a capability called *triggers*.

Triggers allow you to do take actions when something happens in the database.  For instance, if you want to check that values are correct, you can write an `insert`/`update` trigger to check the values and reject improper ones.  Or, if you want to stash deleted records into an audit table, a trigger is the way to go.

What you are describing could be implemented using a trigger on a "select".  Such a beast does not exist.

What are your options?  Well, the simplest is to do this in your application.  When a movie is selected, then you can update views.  Of course, that only increments the views where you have the code.

You can move this code into a stored procedure.  This simplifies the application code.  It just has to "know" to use the stored procedure.  But, there is no enforcement mechanism.

You can make this more enforceable by using permissions.  Basically, don't allow access to the underlying table *except* through the stored procedure.  This is closest to what you want.